# JSoup selecting options from the list java

Tags: java, jsoup

Trying to get the information that is in the option tags but with my path it returns the info with the tags.

```
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("http://timetables.cit.ie:70/studentset.htm");
    conn.timeout(5000); // timeout in milliseconds
    Document doc = conn.get();  
    String title = doc.title(); 


    Elements tBody = doc.select("[id=objectlist] > select > option ");
    System.out.println(tBody);
```

Comment: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get text which will be generated by selected HTML code you should use `text()` method instead of `toString()` method (which is invoked implicitly by `println()`).

Also if you want to get text from each option individually you need to iterate over all selected options.

And instead of `[id=identifier]` you can simply write `#identifier`.

So try with

```
Elements options = doc.select("#objectlist > select > option ");
for (Element option : options){
    System.out.println(option.text());
}
```